# Sugarcrm multi select field dependent on another multi select field

Tags: sugarcrm

It is possible to create dependency between two Multi-select fields through Studio? Suppose I have a Industry Multi-Select and a SubIndustry Multi-Select. When I select an Industry the SubIndustry should show only the related fields?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It's not possible without customization. SugarLogic doesn't play well with multi-selects. You can't even have a single select dependent on a multi-select.

Comment: And how you would do that with customization?

Comment: Writing either very specific custom javascript or some custom javascript plugin that would mimic that behavior. You'd have to get clever or complicated to allow it to work within studio, however.